# Как обратиться к элементам одной процедуры из другой?

Tags: c++, sfml

Как обратиться к элементам одной процедуры из другой?

Есть процедура 1:

```
void Hero::draw(x, y)
{
    sf::RectangleShape block(sf::Vector2f(40, 40));
    block.setPosition(0, 0);
    block.move(x, y);

    _app->draw(block);
}
```

И во второй процедуре нужно обратиться к `block` из первой процедуры, то есть:

```
void Hero::tpto(x, y) 
{
    block.move(x, y);
}
```

Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: никак. ну почти никак.  первый block - это локальная переменная.
Но я знаю, что Вы хотите сделать - вы хотите, что бы прямоугольник переместился. Правильно?

Comment: @KoVadim именно.

Comment: В c++ нет процедур. Только функции.

Answer (score 2):

Локальные переменные уничтожаются при выходе из функции. Переменная `block`, определённая внутри функции `Hero::draw`, не существует вне контекста этой функции.

Если нужно сделать нечто вида `block.move(x, y);` из другой функции-члена класса `Hero`, то вероятнее всего переменная `block` должна быть не локальной, а членом-данных класса. Т.е. где-то в определении класса `Hero` должно быть:

```
class Hero
{
    ...
    sf::RectangleShape block;
    ...
};
```

А сама инициализация `block` где-то в конструкторе. Скорее всего в списке инициализации:

```
Hero::Hero() : block(sf::Vector2f(40, 40))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
void Hero::tpto(x, y, sf::RectangleShape* block = NULL)
{
   if (block)
      block->move(x, y);
}

void Hero::draw(x, y)
{
   sf::RectangleShape block(sf::Vector2f(40, 40));
   block.setPosition(0, 0);
   tpto(x, y, &block);

   _app->draw(block);
}
```

Comment: Мой вызов процедуры в main выглядит так : hero.draw(100, 100) , смогу ли я использовать ту процедуру что вы сделали в моем коде примерно так : hero.tpto(150,150, ) , и что я должен выбрать в качестве 3 аргумента ?